# Pass a Method to call on Obj as Param

Tags: javascript

I was initially going to ask how to do it, but it seems you can pass method names just like you can pass property names. Is this bad practice though? Any reason not to do it?

```
  var actionsObj = {
    writeSomething: function(){console.log('lol');}
  }

  function doSomeAction(writeSomething){
    actionsObj[writeSomething](); 
  };

  doSomeAction('writeSomething'); //executes writeSomething method of actionsObj
```

[Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/hKYOLnTpiUexXd9ruRcz?p=preview)

Comment: No reason not to, if it solves your problem neatly.

Comment: yes. this is fine.

Comment: No problem at all and you can validate the parameter using: typeof writeSomething == "function"

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot guys.

Comment: It can be hard to find all occurrences of `writeSomething` execution as developer can write something like `doSomeAction('write' + 'Something')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this bad practice though?

No.

> Any reason not to do it?

It depends on what you need. Passing a "verb" to a function to choose from a set of pre-set actions is very limited, passing a function itself ("callback") allows the caller to pass arbitrary code.

So this pattern fits if you *want* to limit the possible actions, or if the set of useful actions is restricted by your domain requirements anyway it doesn't matter, but in other situations it feels a bit inflexible.

Compare

```
function doSomeAction(actionName){
    var actionsObj = {
        writeSomething: function(x){ console.log(x); },
        …
    };
    actionsObj[actionName]('lol'); 
}

doSomeAction('writeSomething');
doSomeAction('someOtherOption'); // restricted by the callee
…
```

to

```
function doSomeAction(action){
    action('lol'); 
}

doSomeAction(function(x){ console.log(x); });
doSomeAction(anyOtherFunction); // chosen by the caller
…
```

The major difference is where in the code the possible actions are given. Does the `doSomeAction` need to know about all of them, are they the same every time?

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand (has to do with my very limited experience with JS callbacks). Would I just pass actionsObj in this case and call methods on it?

Comment: Nah, you'd pass the action method itself, you most likely wouldn't even have that object. Whether you have such an "object of available actions" depends on your use case - if it seems sensible, then the verb pattern is fine.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a bad practice, it is actually a common thing to do.

It serves, mainly, for code separation, or for making generic implementations, for example, an http request with a custom callback.

Comment: writeSomething is 'writeSomething', I just named the param the same as the string because I was writing this quickly